# Jekyll default (layout) Front Matter doesn't work: fixed

Tags: yaml, jekyll, yaml-front-matter

I was trying to set different layouts depending on the directory of the pages, like:

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: "pages"
    values:
      layout: "default"
  -
    scope:
      path: "www/grid"
      type: "pages"
    values:
      layout: "grid"
  -
    scope:
      path: "www/product"
      type: "pages"
    values:
      layout: "product"
```

As recommended, I saved the `_config.yml` file, stopped and rerun the `jekyll serve` command. Yet, after reloading the pages, nothing seemed affected.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem, I:

1. Saved the `_config.yml` file
2. Stopped the `jekyll serve` command
3. **Deleted the `.jekyll-metadata` file**
4. Run the `jekyll serve` command

After that everything worked fine.

The `.jekyll-metadata` (which I assume is some cache) file is rebuilt after the `serve` command.